# Is it possible to tell a python script to stop at some point and give you the hand interactively, for example with ipython?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a script that does a lot of stuff, and doesn't work well somewhere near the end. I'd love to be able to add a `start_ipython()` function at that point, which would stop the script at this point, and let me inspect variables and so on with ipython. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that this has changed in IPython-0.11.  Instead of what is described below, simply use the following import:

```
from IPython import embed as shell
```

The answer below works for IPython versions prior to 0.11.

---

In the region where you want to drop into ipython, define this

```
def start_ipython():
   from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
   shell = IPShellEmbed()
   shell()
```

and call `start_ipython` where you want to drop into the interpreter.

This will drop you into an interpreter and will preserve the `locals()` at that point.

If you want a regular shell, do this

```
def start_python():
   import code
   code.interact()
```

Check the documentation for the above functions for details. I'd recommend that you try the ipython one and if it throws an `ImportError`, switch to normal so that it will work even if ipython is not installed.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph (try iPython first, code.interact on import error)

Comment: Well, that's what the `shell` command for the turbogears framework does and I liked the behaviour. Thanks for your +1.

Comment: If the def is a problem, you can turn this into a one-liner: `import IPython; IPython.Shell.IPShellEmbed()()`. You can use it like `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way is to use the built-in debugger. At the point you want execution to stop, just do:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and you'll be dumped into the pdb shell, which allows you to inspect variables and change them.

There is also an external `ipdb` package which you can get via `easy_install` which should work the same way.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to use ipython instead of the pdb shell, though?